# Template specialization Clang 10.0

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code example:

```
template<int PARAM>
struct GetTypeByInt;

template<>
struct GetTypeByInt<0>
{
    using type = int;
}

template<>
struct GetTypeByInt<1>
{
    using type = float;
}

template<int PARAM>
struct SomeClass
{
    static_assert((PARAM == 0) || (PARAM == 1), "Incorrect type.");

    void doSomething();
};

template<int PARAM>
void SomeClassM<PARAM>::doSomething()
{
    GetTypeByInt<PARAM>::type value;
    ...
}
```

This code works on the VS2017 without any problems, but on the Clang 10.0(XCode) I have the following error:

```
Unexpected type name 'type': expected expression
```

For example, if I remove one of the specialization of the GetTypeByInt<0> or GetTypeByInt<1>, it will work, but together it doesn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, a `type` is not a `value` (and so may not be assigned to one). Did you translate your problem reliably to this [mre]?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made small mistake